Indexing changing the whole pandas DataFrame
I am kind of surprised by the behaviour of indexind this post they solved an initial doubt about accesing the rows that have NaNs values in them, but I see that when I omit the
.any(axis=1)

And just write
df[df.isna()

It returns a DataFrame with the same shape as df but with ALL entries as NaN. Can somebody explain me why this is?

The behavior you're observing is due to how pandas handles boolean indexing when you omit the .any(axis=1) method. When you use df.isna(), it returns a DataFrame of the same shape as df, but with True where the values are NaN and False otherwise.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, np.nan],
    'B': [4, np.nan, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
})

print(df.isna())

Output:
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False   True  False
2   True  False  False

When you then do df[df.isna()], you're applying boolean indexing, expecting to filter the DataFrame. However, df[df.isna()] isn't how pandas is designed to work for filtering rows or cells based on conditions.
print(df[df.isna()])

Output:
      A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN

When you pass a boolean DataFrame like df.isna() into another DataFrame (like df[df.isna()]), pandas interprets this as an attempt to select specific elements rather than filtering rows. But because the boolean DataFrame doesn't align with the DataFrame being indexed, pandas essentially returns a DataFrame filled with NaN where it couldn't match the structure.
The reason you see a DataFrame filled with NaN is that pandas can't properly match the boolean DataFrame to the original df for indexing, so it returns a DataFrame of the same shape with all NaN values.
Hope this answers your question.

This is because if you enter a boolean data frame in square brackets as a target for the data frame, it will return NaN for all but the locations that are True.
You might want to practice with the following example.
new example :
import pandas as pd
data = [[2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2], [4, 5, 5], [5, 1, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

df:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     2     3     4
1     4     3     2
2     4     5     5
3     5     1     3

run this code:
out = df[df == 4]

out:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   NaN   NaN  4.00
1  4.00   NaN   NaN
2  4.00   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN


df[df.isna()] will eventually return all non-nulls as NaNs. The originally null locations will still return null, resulting in an all-NaN data frame.

Assuming:
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,None]])

Using df[df.isna().any(axis=1)] acts as loc (df.loc[df.isna().any(axis=1)]) and performs boolean indexing. It treats the 1D boolean Series as a selector for the rows.
df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]

   0   1
1  3 NaN

df.loc[df.isna().any(axis=1)]

   0   1
1  3 NaN

While df[df.isna()] acts as where (df.where(df.isna())). It masks the values based on the 2D (DataFrame) boolean mask (by default the False values in the mask become nan/None).:
df[df.isna()]

    0   1
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN

df.where(df.isna())

    0   1
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN

But, as you can notice, boolean indexing with a 2D array wouldn't work:
df.loc[df.isna()]
# ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key


Good explanation but you should add that the 'where' when False returns NaN, otherwise it is confusing. The fact that df.isna() is a dataframe and not a Series is also notable

@MrE that's a valid point, I added some more details.
